# Copying url file from Windows 10 computer to Samsung Galaxy A5 fails, system sound sounds

Tags: windows, file-transfer, url

I have created a .url file using Windows Explorer on a Windows 10 computer. When I try to copy the .url file to my Samsung Galaxy A5 phone the file cannot be copied to my phone. I just hear a strange sound, which is either SystemSound.Asterisk or SystemSound.Exclamation. I cannot tell the difference between these two sounds.
What causes that I am not able to copy the .url file and why does the sound sound (as specified above) instead?

Comment: For sending an URL from your PC to a smartphone I would not use a URL file - it is very generic, and I don't think many apps can handle this file format. better try one of the various playlist formats (M3U, PLS, what ever your player on Android supports).

Comment: I just want to know why I am not able to copy an url File to my phone, but other files as well.There must be a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use URL Opener to open the file in Firefox for Android. It works great. Copying via FTP or WEBDAV works, but not when Windows PC is connected to Android via USB.

Comment: Could you please explain the last sentence of your answer?

Comment: Norbert... to add to my last sentence... copying a .URL file via FTP or WEBDAV works, but using Win10, regular file explorer i.e. via MTP does not seem to work...
It is still very annoying to me since the USB method is the fastest.

Comment: example: A Folder with Show/Movie... which includes .url files for the Show/Movie, its actors, etc... like links to imdb,com.
Windows File Explorer (via USB) will copy the folder and its contents, BUT will "bleep" for the .url files and not copy those over.
Frustrating, but there is probably a simple solution.